# Setting Checked property of a Button in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am having a group of buttons in a `Column` and i have set `autoExclusive : true`. Now only one button can be checked as expected. But, how to disable the checked state if i click on the button which is already checked? Following is the code:

```
Column {
    id: column

    Button {
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("button 1")
        autoExclusive : true
        checkable : true
        background: Rectangle {
            color:checked ? "red" : "white"
        }
    }

    Button {
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("button 2")
        autoExclusive : true
        checkable : true
        background: Rectangle {
            color:checked ? "red" : "white"
        }
    }

    Button {
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("button 3")
        autoExclusive : true
        checkable : true
        background: Rectangle {
            color:checked ? "red" : "white"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this by using [ButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-buttongroup.html) :

```
Column {
    id: column

    Button {
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("button 1")
        ButtonGroup.group: btnGrp //assign buttongroup
        checkable : true
        background: Rectangle {
            color:checked ? "red" : "white"
        }
    }

    Button {
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("button 2")
        ButtonGroup.group: btnGrp //assign buttongroup
        checkable : true
        background: Rectangle {
            color:checked ? "red" : "white"
        }
    }

    Button {
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("button 3")
        ButtonGroup.group: btnGrp //assign buttongroup
        checkable : true
        background: Rectangle {
            color:checked ? "red" : "white"
        }
    }
}

ButtonGroup {
    id:btnGroup
}
```

Now loop through `btnGrp.buttons` and can check the button state to true or false and also can get checked button by accessing `btnGrp.checkedButton`.

Answer (score 0):

```
color: button2.checked ? "red" : "white"
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27301747)